# woocommerce don't display single products description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm customizing my woocommerce to fit the layout of my custom theme. I have an issue with the product description, it will not be displayed in the single product page, only the short description will be showed. I don't know why there is this problem, I didn't touched the relative hook. Is there a fix for this? I have this remove hooks in my functions.php file:

```
/* WooCommerce default hooks remotion */
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_catalog_ordering', 30 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );
  //remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
  //remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_category_title', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory_title', 'woocommerce_subcategory_thumbnail', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_product_archive_description', 10 );

  //remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

and this is the template for a single product

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content within loops
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.6.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

// Ensure visibility.
if ( empty( $product ) || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}
?>
<div <?php wc_product_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3', $product ); ?>>
    <div class="card shop-product-card">
    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_title - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_close - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check you `content-single-product.php`. is there any `do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );` ?

Comment: the template posted is the one you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

please make sure that you have declared add_theme_support('woocommerce') in your functions.php